# How to differentiate class properties using user-defined tags (custom-attributes)

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

**Background:**
I have a custom class, which represents a Data Base Table, each property corresponding to a table column. The properties can be classified in three ways.

**Example:** Take for example a Person object.

- MetaProperties: (Columns that are needed by the program)

  - Person_ID: *used in table for indexing etc...*
  - UserDefinedType: *(UDT), complex class handling write-permission on the table*.
  - Timestamp: *needed to handle the UDT in C# DataTables*
- RealProperties: (actual traits that describe the real Person)

  - FullName
  - DateOfBirth
  - PlaceOfBirth
  - EyeColor
  - etc... *(many more)*
- RawDataProperties: (these columns hold raw data from external sources)

  - Phys_EyeColor: *the eye-color, as directly imported from the physical traits database, may be in unknown format, may have conflicting value with entry from other db, or any other data quality issue...*
  - HR_FullName: *full name as given in HR file*
  - Web_FullName: *full name as taken from a web form*
  - Web_EyeColor: *eye color as taken from web form*
  - etc...

  public class Person
  {

  ```
  #region MetaProperties

  public int Person_ID { get; set; }
  public UserDefinedType UDT { get; set; }
  public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

  #endregion


  #region RealProperties

  public string FullName { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
  public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
  public Color EyeColor { get; set; }
  //...

  #endregion


  #region RawDataProperties

  public string Phys_EyeColor { get; set; }
  public string Phys_BodyHeight { get; set; }

  public string Web_FullName { get; set; }
  public string Web_EyeColor { get; set; }

  public string HR_FullName { get; set; }
  //...
  #endregion
  ```

  }

**Question:** How can I programmatically differentiate between these three types of properties in my Person class? The goal is to be able to iterate through properties of a certain type using `System.Reflection` or some other organisational construct. Pseudocode:

```
foreach(Property prop in Person.GetPropertiesOfType("RealProperty"){
... doSmth(prop);
}
```

I'm thinking about writing custom Attributes, and hanging them on to the properties, sort of like taggin.
But since I know nothing about custom Attributes, I would like to ask if I'm going down the proper path, or if there are any other better ways of doing this.

**Note:** the shown example may may not be the best in terms of program design, and I am well aware that inheritance or splitting up the class otherwise could solve this problem. But that is not my question - **I want to know if properties in a class can be tagged or somehow differentiated between using custom categories**.

Comment: Side note: Properties have getters and setters.  Your examples don't, so they're technically Fields. Usually it doesn't matter much, but if you try iterating over all Properties but you declared them as Fields, then you won't get the results you expect.

Comment: @Bobson y sorry, my bad for skimping on the example. I'll correct it to properties...

Comment: No worries - it's just a heads up because I've run afoul of that many times myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with custom attributes.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class PropertyAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
       public PropertyType Type { get; private set; }
       public PropertyAttribute (PropertyType type) { Type = type; }
    }

    public enum PropertyType
    {
       Meta,
       Real,
       Raw,
    }
```

Then, you can do this with each property or field:

```
[PropertyType(PropertyType.Meta)]
public int Person_ID;
[PropertyType(PropertyType.Real)]
public string FullName;
[PropertyType(PropertyType.Raw)]
public string Phys_EyeColor;
```

Then you can access it with something like

```
foreach (PropertyAttribute attr in this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PropertyAttribute), false))
{
    // Do something based on attr.Type
}
```